# Import data from other Excel workbooks using formulas for sheets

Tags: excel

I'm conducting a summary for some data which I import from a bunch of Excel files. These are constructed with a sheet for each month, so if I want to access the cell O5 for January I have to call that as:

```
 ='C:\path\[Filename]January'!$O$5
```

Where my summary is constructed as:

```
       January   February ....
cost
```

where the cost for January is the O5 referenced earlier, and the cost for February is:

```
 ='C:\path\[Filename]February'!$O$5
```

etc. Is there a way to insert a formula for the sheet it will call so when I "drag" out the cell in my summary file it will iterate each cost for each month by only altering the sheets to call? I've tried to google this but searching for linking to sheets etc. only shows how to do the "regular" import from other Excel sheets.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I've tried to do:

```
=INDIRECT(" 'C:\path\[filename]"&A94&" '!$O$5")
```

Where A94 is "January" in my "summary workbook" and where O5 is the cell representing the cost in the workbook referenced to by C:\Path...

I've tried both to have the cell A94 in my summary workbook (which I must have, since I don't want to write the month in every file I will reference to) and tried to have A94 as January for the workbook I'm referencing to.

However, in both cases it returns ######. I'm having the referenced workbook open.

Excluding the " " Before 'C: and after $O$5 gives me the error that "A94" is not a worksheet for the file referenced to through C:\path..

EDIT2: Also tried to have A1 as reference for January in my summary sheet. Evaluating this expression gives:

```
=INDIRECT(" 'C:\path\[filename]January '!$O$5 ")
```

and the comment "A function in this formula causes the result to change every time the calculation sheet is evauluated. The final evaluation step will match the result in the cell, but the intermediate steps may not"

And then "REFERENCE! when I try to evaluate the next step.

Does anyone have any idea of what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `=INDIRECT()` formula, like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'C:\path\[Filename]"&A1&"'!$O$5")
```

Where `A1` contains month name. If you make a column of month names you can then use the same formula with `B1` for February, `C1` for march etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to implement that, but I've gotten errors. I've edited the OP.

Comment: Why do you put spaces there between `"` and `'`? There should be none.

Comment: Thanks, removing the space got me the correct result!